# Not always being notified of new responses

Tags: support, responses

I've seen this discussed in the context of a couple of other questions but not on its own. I'm finding that randomly I'll revisit a question where I've left a comment in the past, and be surprised to find that someone replied to me - I was just never notified.

I have not noticed this in relation to comments against answers I've provided, only comments against my comments. This isn't across the board (like I've opted out of the new Inbox or anything), as I do get some notifications - just not all.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior? Is this covered in another question I wasn't able to find? Is this intended behavior?

Comment: Can you point to some examples?  Without seeing examples, I can only guess that you aren't being properly replied to.

Comment: I'm having this problem too.  People are starting to omit the @user prefix when they shouldn't.  It isn't obvious when it is required.

Comment: That may be it Rebecca, I'd have to go through and cross-ref the recent examples to know for sure. Perhaps my expectation is that if I comment on an answer, and then someone else comments after me, I'd be notified, but I suppose it makes more sense if they explicitly reply to my @user prefix. I think Hans has a point, that people don't necessarily know that they can do this at all, never mind when. I wonder if it would be a ridiculous feature request to have some way to be notified of any additions/changes to any question I've acted on (without having to manually favorite).

Comment: @hans per the "help" link that appears just under every "add comment" button: *The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work*

Comment: There are some important caveats to the @reply system. A big one that people often forget is that only the *first* matching user will be notified using the @user syntax. So you can't notify multiple people in a single comment. I've also thought I've seen "bugs" or random failings here, but upon closer inspection, it turns out to be a misunderstanding of how the system works. More details are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: @jeff - could you treat @ginger specially?

Comment: @cody ok, I made it so that we explicitly reject any comments with more than one `@username` in them, since they can basically never work. Exception is made if the comment contains backtick.

Comment: I'm having this too, and I think it's a side effect of the `auto-remove unnecessary @attribution` "feature" that was added recently.  People are less consistently using `@name` now.