# Don't count @blah in a comment as attempting to message a user unless that user is indeed involved in the discussion

Tags: feature-request, comments

Recently the comment system was changed to allow only a single use of `@blah` in a comment; otherwise, the comment is rejected with the message "you can only @message one user..."

However, I recently tried to post a comment like the following:

> @Adam Davis: Some content that does not matter. Blah Blah Blah. And of course the @stuff is related to some other content that does not matter. This message not posted as it was posted in the question to avoid trolling. Thank you.

"@stuff" in this case was not intending to invoke the user messaging system at all; it was intended to talk about the fact that comments have a feature which repsonds to @anythingGoesHere. It would be nice if the check for multiple uses of the alert system did not reject comments which did not refer to any specific user involved in the post to which the comment is applied.

Comment: Just FYI, you can use a backtick (`) anywhere in the post to circumvent this restriction.

Comment: @waiwai933 Do you know if this is documented anywhere? I can't find it.

Comment: @Jeremy Jeff's second comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98954/not-always-being-notified-of-new-responses).

Answer (score 5):

Just place it within a code block and it won't trigger name notifications.

Comment: +1 for a reasonable workaround, but it would be nice if this "just work"ed. :)