# Get notified when the OP comments right after our comment and uses no "@"

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, comment-replies

I'm a bit hesitant to ask this question because I know there has been a lot of discussion on the topic of notifications (or pings). I've especially taken a very good look at [When exactly do I get comment notifications?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125208/168269) and [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/168269). But there is one thing that causes me some trouble.

Often people forget the `@` in comments. And because of this rule

> [If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is forgotten.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/168269)

I won't always get notified of responses to my comment when others also commented. This situation occurs very often, I could show many examples in my own activity log.

This means that when I comment on a post to ask for clarification I always have to check these comments later to see if the OP responded to it, because I cannot count on them to have used the `@`. If the OP took the effort to respond I feel I should at least read the response and possibly act on it.

**Could we get notified when the OP comments *right after* our comment *and* had not used `@`?**

I think this would be pretty intuitive behaviour.

It would not catch all cases, I know, <del>but probably the majority of them</del>. And yes, it would probably cause some redundant notifications. But then, false positives are likely to be interesting to me too as I'm clearly involved in the post.

For dupe detectives: similar question: [Not always being notified of new responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98954/168269) (but no proposed solution).

Comment: Personally I would like to be notified when a question I have in favorites is commented or answered.

Comment: Right, more notifications... <shrug>

Comment: `Often people (including myself) forget the "@" in comments.` Don't forget it. Problem solved.

Comment: @YannisRizos. That's too easy. Most new users don't even know the feature.

Comment: @GertArnold Most new users don't know about a lot of our features...

Comment: I agree this would make the rules more consistent.

Comment: "...but probably the majority of them" - Eh, I'm not so sure about that. I suspect the 'Person A comments, Person B comments, OP indirectly responds to Person A' scenario is much more common, and this would just result in Person B getting notification of the response intended for Person A.

Comment: Sure, it happens, of course. Hard to give rock-solid numbers of how many cases would be fixed.

Comment: I'm more concerned about how many more people would be notified of things that weren't necessarily relevant to them, personally.

Comment: @TimStone It's only about comments from the OP, not others. If the OP comments to a comment higher up in the list they usually use the "@". It's in the quick responses to the last comment they get that the "@" is often forgotten. For me this is still an issue.

Comment: @TimStone In such a case, person B can then ping person A, and the OP learns how to ping.